# How to query Slick with an optional foreign key to return all records with and without relationship?

Tags: slick, slick-2.0, play-slick

I have an optional foreign key defined on Event which goes to EventType. I want to query for all events, even those events which have a None (null) event type. This is the foreign key defined on Event.

```
def eventTypeId = column[Option[Long]]("event_type_id")
def eventType = foreignKey("event_type", eventTypeId, EventTypes.eventTypes)(_.id)
```

My initial query is as follows but it only returns those records which do have the foreign key set since the foreign key is optional. How?

```
(for {
   p <- events
   e <- p.eventType
} yield (p, e))
```

I wish to see all events with AND without the foreign key set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking for is for Slick to produce an outer join in that situation.  I realize you've tagged this as a Slick 2 question, but the enhancement is slated for Slick 3.2: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/179

In the meantime, you can manage the join yourself. For example:

```
events.leftJoin(eventTypes).on(_.eventTypeId === _.id).
map { case (e, et) => (e, et.name.?) }
```

... which will ultimately give you a result of `Seq[(Event, Option[String])]` (or similar, assuming you have a `name` that's a `String`).

Comment: Non-required foreign key should be supported more easily. What you gave me works though, so I will go with that for the moment thanks!